# INSERT MULTIPLE EN CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Buen día, estoy queriendo hacer un insert múltiple a 2 tablas de una base de datos externa mediante Codeigniter.

```
public function insertMultiple($data,$valor)
{
    //conectar base de datos externa
    $BD_EXTERNA = $this->load->database('dbexterna',TRUE);

    //primera consulta - insert
    $BD_EXTERNA ->insert('tabla1', $data);
    $dato = $BD_EXTERNA >insert_id();

    //capturar el id de la persona que realizo el registro en la otra base datos
    $query2 = $BD_EXTERNA >select("id_user")
                            ->from("t_usuarios")
                            ->where("t_valor",$valor)
                            ->where("cat",'12')
                            ->get();
    $query2->result();

    $BD_EXTERNA >insert('tabla2', $dato,$query2);
}
```

Lo que intento hacer es:

1. Instar el registro en la tabla1 (funciona)
2. Capturar el id del registro de la tabla1(será utilizado luego) - (no funciona)
3. Capturar el id de la persona que realizo el registro en la tabla de usuarios de la base de datos externa. (funciona)
4. Insertar el id de registro del tabla1 + id de la persona que realizo el registro, en la tabla2 (no funciona)

Alguna ayuda por favor, de antemano mil gracias.

Answer (score 0):

`$dato = $BD_EXTERNA >insert_id();` esta mala ya que no esta bien puesta la Flecha
`->insert_id()` tambien  podrias crear una funcion que retorne el id de la primera inserción y usarla dentro de tu funcion `insertMultiple()` como este ejemplo.

```
function insertPrimeraTabla($data)
{
    $BD_EXTERNA = $this->load->database('dbexterna',TRUE);

    $BD_EXTERNA->insert('tabla1', $data);
    $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();

    return  $insert_id;
}
```

y en la funcion lo llamas asi

```
public function insertMultiple($data,$valor)
{
//Retorno del id 
$idTable = $this->insertPrimeraTabla($data)
$BD_EXTERNA = $this->load->database('dbexterna',TRUE);

$query2 = $BD_EXTERNA->select("id_user")
                        ->from("t_usuarios")
                        ->where("t_valor",$valor)
                        ->where("cat",'12')
                        ->get();
$query2->result();
//error por tercer parametro es boolean
$BD_EXTERNA->insert('tabla2', $idTable,$query2);
}
```

en la documentacion de Codeigniter puedes ver que el tercer parametro de la funcion insert es $escape y pide un Boolean con lo cual no inserta:
[codeigniter insert](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::insert)

por lo que el insert de la hacia la segunda tabla deberia ser asi

```
    $BD_EXTERNA->insert('tabla2', $query2);
```

(no se como es el retorno de una $query2  , pero podrias modificarla y añadirle  el valor de $idTable para luego insertarla)

por lo que lei result() devuelve una matriz de objeto, entonces podrias agregar el $idTable simplemente asi:

```
$query2['id_tabla'] = $idTable;
```

donde 'id_tabla es el nombre de la columna de tu tabla
y luego hacer la insercion.